# Is it possible to edit the sizes of images/icons inside a button with a text below in xml android studio?

Tags: android, xml

I can't edit the size of the icon/image for my button. Making a Image Button tag or putting the icon/image in the background doesn't work because in the image button tag, the text would disappear simply because the image button displays image only while putting the icon/image in the background, the text would go to the center and not to the area I wanted it to put.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understood well, you want to put an image inside a button with text, with the text under the image.

If so, You can put an image and a text inside a vertical linear layout, this way you can edit the image and text separatly

Comment: The main problem is the image/icon, I want to edit the size of the image/icon.

Comment: You want to put an image and a text inside a button, with the text under the image, right? If you use a linear layout and handle the click on the linear layout, it is easier to adjust the image and text exactly how you want